# Is the following linear transformation onto, one to one or both?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The linear map $f : \mathbb{Z}_7^3 → \mathbb{Z}_7^3$ given by $$x=\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3} \in \mathbb{Z}_7^3->f(x):=\pmatrix{6 \;\;\;0 \;\;\;3 \\ 2 \;\;\;2 \;\;\;5\\1\;\;\;0\;\;\;1}\ \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3}\in \mathbb{Z}_7^3 $$

Attempt:

In RREF the 3x3 matrix given above is the identity. Therefore its null space only includes the zero vector which happens if and only if the mapping is injective. However, I'm unsure about what the presence of the vector containing $x_1,x_2,x_3$ does to affect this. And I think this mapping would be surjective since we can always find an $f(x)$ for every $x$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $\mathbb Z_7^3$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes I did I'm sorry I'm new to latex :)

Answer (score 1):

It is both, this matrix has an inverse.

If $Ax=Ay$, then we have $x=y$, by premultiplying $A^{-1}$

Similarly, to solve for $x$ in $Ax=y$, we just have to premultiplying $A^{-1}$ on both sides.

Comment: The answer is correct. Since 7 is prime, Z/7Z is a field. The matrix has an inverse because its determinant , over the field Z/7Z is 6, which is not 0.